# How do I protect LUKS from Ram Dumps?

Tags: encryption, lvm, luks

I want to protect my data from anyone who wants to access it, including the NSA.

I used whole disk encryption on my Kubuntu INSTALL, and I never do anything half-way.

I looked up how to crack LUKS, and it took me some time but eventually I found this article on how anyone with a live USB can crack LUKS encryption.

https://0x00sec.org/t/breaking-encryption-hashed-passwords-luks-devices/811

How do I protect my Disk from such an attack?
That is until quantum computers break RSA 4096.

Comment: That article does **not** describe a procedure of cracking LUKS. The article describes getting the **hashed** password from a memory dump. The hashed password will do you no good. **You would still need to brute-force the hash.**

Comment: RSA itself is not susceptible to quantum computing attacks. Where did you get that misinformation? Also, if you're paranoid enough to worry about government-sponsored hackers, good luck protecting yourself against [crowbar key escrow](https://www.xkcd.com/538/)!

Comment: It isn't, but it will in the not-so-distant future. Quatum computing is the best promise in terms of hacking encryption.

Comment: Wanna bet?http://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/computing/hardware/encryptionbusting-quantum-computer-practices-factoring-in-scalable-fiveatom-experiment

Comment: nothing is unhackable, and we are closer than ever to cracking encryption. just you wait till quotum computers get a little more advanced.

Comment: [Crypto.SE] disagrees that breaking RSA is anywhere near viable in the foreseeable future without some very unexpected and very unlikely break-through. See for instance [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44386/41425), [2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9480/41425), [3](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/436/41425), or a search for [`[rsa] [post-quantum-cryptography]`](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rsa+post-quantum-cryptography). Anyway, this is not the right place to discuss this.

Comment: @android dev actually,  If we can grab the memory, all we need to do is find the hash, run it through a password cracker and volia! We’ve got the plain text password.

Comment: @JohanLiebert: Fortunately it ain't that easy. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, not with LUKS. The possibility of this attack is a feature, not a bug. It allows the system to keep the volume open after resume-from-suspension.

However, cryptography works in your favour to mitigate the consequences of this attack to a point where it becomes unviable if you choose

1. a “secure” pass phrase hash algorithm (see the `--hash` option of `cryptsetup(8)`) and
2. a “secure” pass phrase or key store.

For (1.) the default should be fine with a reasonably recent kernel and `cryptsetup` version. You can always change the hash algorithm at a later point (provided you know the correct pass phrase or volume key).

For (2.) refer to common guidelines to choose pass phrases. Many people seem to agree that [Randall Munroe's comic](https://xkcd.com/936/) illustrates a viable scheme for that choice. Another option are keys stored on smartcards. You can also pair the two.

Comment: It might bear noting that storing the hash in memory is related to resume from suspend.  So, it's not a bug.  It's necessary to have resume from suspend without a password entry unless you're using a physical token.

Comment: So in a nutshell, the solution to this feature is to...?

Comment: Fork luks and have a pam module that only supports USB tokens.  That's just how I'ld fix it.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @RobotHumans: Thanks for the hint! I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JohanLiebert: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.